# Using Jersey 2.1 with CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey, guava, cdi

I try to use `Jersey 2.1` and `CDI` in my `Java EE 7` project which is deployed on `Glassfish 4.0.`

Jersey modules depend on [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). But using Guava libraries (14.0.1) with CDI results the following exception being thrown.

```
CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)].
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI has some questionable behavior. We think we have two workarounds: [one that you can do yourself](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433#c20) and [one that will work automatically when we release Guava 15.0](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433#c23). You can [read more about the problem here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433#c22).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Guava classes are annotated, and CDI tries to inject dependencies into them.

The glassfish/modules directory contains a guava.jar. so simply setting the guava dependency to provided (or test) in maven solves the problem.