# CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, apache-spark, jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi

Help please, im lost here and im losing my mind, im new to spark-hadoop and i got this problem, i looked everything and still couldnt find any solution i know its because Guava but i dont know what is the problem exactly and how to fix it.

im working with netbeans and glassfish. when i deploy my jee application i got this error even. i tried to deploy without the code( logic of the app/ the work that the app supposed to do), like an empty app with just welcome index and jars files that i need. but it didnt work so im sure that its a jars problem.

PS: i tested the app logic and jars in windows app and it worked perfectly  so i think it a problem that has to do with glassfish server ? im not too sure please help im really desperate for the solution.THANKS

Stacktrace :

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager.<init>(ServiceManager.java:0)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:291)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:529)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:515)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:490)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:419)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsatisfied dependencies for type Set<Service> with qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696185/unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-setservice-with-qualifiers)

Comment: @k.Nicholas i've already seen this post but i didnt understand What to do, i updated the guava jdk but the same error still happening

Answer (score 0):

asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false

After setting this I was able to deploy a vanilla WAR file in Glassfish 4.x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).